# Dynamically add Element from Custom BaseAdapter for ListView

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I have this Custom BaseAdapter. On a row I have 3 spinners. I want that after each spinner on a row has a selected item, another row is dinamically added to the listview and shown. How can I achieve this? This is what I tried.

```
public MateriiAdapter (Activity a, ArrayList<YTOMaterie> orar) {
        this.orar = orar;
        activity = a;

        inflater = ( LayoutInflater )activity.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    public int getCount() {
        if(orar.size()<=0)
            return 1;
        return orar.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder{
        public NoDefaultSpinner spinnerOra;
        public NoDefaultSpinner spinnerMinute;
        public NoDefaultSpinner spinnerMaterii;

    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View vi = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView==null){

            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_materie, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.spinnerOra = (NoDefaultSpinner) vi.findViewById(R.id.spOra);
            holder.spinnerMinute = (NoDefaultSpinner) vi.findViewById(R.id.spMinute);
            holder.spinnerMaterii = (NoDefaultSpinner) vi.findViewById(R.id.spMaterii);

            final boolean[] oraSelectata = {false};
            final boolean[] minSelectat={false};
            final boolean[] materieSelectata={false};

            holder.spinnerOra.setOnItemSelectedListener((AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener) new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                           int arg2, long arg3) {
                    oraSelectata[0] = true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

                }
            });

            holder.spinnerMinute.setOnItemSelectedListener((AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener) new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                           int arg2, long arg3) {
                    minSelectat[0] = true;

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

                }
            });

            holder.spinnerMaterii.setOnItemSelectedListener((AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener) new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                           int arg2, long arg3) {
                    materieSelectata[0] = true;
                    if(materieSelectata[0] == true && oraSelectata[0] == true
                            && minSelectat[0] == true) {
                        YTOMaterie y =  new YTOMaterie();
                        orar.add(y);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        materieSelectata[0] = false;
                        oraSelectata[0] = false;
                        minSelectat[0] = false;
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

                }
            });

            vi.setTag( holder );
        }
        else
            holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();

        if(orar.size()<=0) {
        } else {
            tempValue=null;
            tempValue = ( YTOMaterie ) orar.get( position );





        }
        return vi;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

ok I have taken example of two simple Spinner which change dynamically depend on each other here is code you can take as many spinner you want and dynamically change value on their onItemSelectedListener() reply if you not get answar want you want..

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    course=new ArrayList<String>();
    techbranch=new ArrayList<String>();
    lawbranch=new ArrayList<String>();
    branch=new ArrayList<String>();


    course.add("Course");
    course.add("Tech");
    course.add("Law");


    techbranch.add("CS");
    techbranch.add("IT");
    techbranch.add("ME");
    techbranch.add("ECE");


    lawbranch.add("CRIME LAW");
    lawbranch.add("LABOUR LAW");
    lawbranch.add("CORPORATE Law");
    lawbranch.add("BUSINESS Law");

    spinner1=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

    adapter1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,course);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);

    adapter2=new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, branch);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);

    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos,
        long id) {

    switch(pos)
    {
    case 1:
        branch.clear();
        branch.addAll(techbranch);
        adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
        break;
    case 2:
        branch.clear();
        branch.addAll(lawbranch);
        adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
        break;

    }
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {



}
```

Comment: This isn't what I asked

Comment: you implements onItemSeletcedListener on top of class register the spinner which you want to listen event and at the OnItemClickListener dynamically update adapter that you want to change and then call notifydatasetchanged() you will get what you want...try this

Comment: you don't say sherlock. this is what I am trying

Comment: please provide more detail what you actually want???   you have written in your problem statement " I want that after each spinner on a row has a selected item, another row is dinamically added to the listview and shown" so i have written code for dynamically adding values in spinner .